# Forcing size to an image returned from a script

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I have the below JavaScript code

```
<script src="https://www.annuncigratuiti.net/reva/index.php?section=serve&id=40&keyword=agrigento&output=js"></script>
```

There is an image on this JS code with size. I don't have access to the source code so I can't change it.

I want to know if there is any way or a trick to force different sizes to this image inside this JS code.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: @RichardDobron answer works well. But if the size is fixed I advise you to use CSS

Comment: By the way, the code returned from that URL is terrible, and generally, I wouldn't let external resources inject code into my website. That's just a security vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom query selector:

```
<script src="https://www.annuncigratuiti.net/reva/index.php?section=serve&id=40&keyword=agrigento&output=js"></script>

<script>
    var adImage = document.querySelector("a>img[width='500'][height='500']");
  
    adImage.style.height = '100px';
    adImage.style.width = '200px';
</script>
```